# parameter passed via javascript - server tag not well formed

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

TemplateField of a gridview column.

The OnClientClick keeps causing a "server tag not well formed error".  Any ideas?

```
 <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" ImageUrl='../../images/20X20%20Dialog%20Box.png'
      OnClientClick='<%# string.Format("javascript: LoadPhysiologicalChart('{0}','{1}');", Eval("code"), txtMRN.ClientID)%>'  AlternateText="Chart Data" />
```

Thanks...

Comment: Why didn't you tag it also ASP and HTML?

Answer (score 0):

It's the single-quotes. ASP.NET gets a little picky with the types of quotes you have on data-bound controls.

One thing: get rid of the `javascript:` - that's not necessary in an `onclick` event.

Try this, with escaped double-quotes instead:

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server"
    ImageUrl='../../images/20X20%20Dialog%20Box.png'
    OnClientClick='<%# string.Format("LoadPhysiologicalChart(\"{0}\",\"{1}\");", Eval("code"), txtMRN.ClientID)%>'
    AlternateText="Chart Data"
/>
```

Answer (score -1):

Can you try the following ?

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" ImageUrl='../../images/20X20%20Dialog%20Box.png'
      OnClientClick="LoadPhysiologicalChart('<%#Eval("code";) %>','<%#Eval("txtMRN.ClientID";) %>');" AlternateText="Chart Data" />
```